# Not able to install skbuild

Tags: python, cmake

I am trying to install "CMake" with command

```
pip3 install CMake.
```

Its gives an error for a module "skbuild"

```
from skbuild import setup, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'
```

But but when tried to install skbuild with command

```
pip3 install skbuild
```

it gives error

```
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement skbuild (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for skbuild".
```

I am not able to solve this error. Please help. I trying the implementation it on Window 10. Using Python 3.7.0. I tried couple of versions of pip3 (10.0.1, 9.0.3, 9.0.2, 9.0.1). Nothing is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are pre-compiled binaries available on [THIS](https://cmake.org/download/) page for Windows as MSI packages and ZIP files. You can find the one for the OS you are using.

If you want to proceed with your current approach then can you can probably refer [THIS LINK](https://bugs.python.org/issue30573)

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded the  ZIP version. Extracted and set the path variables correctly. It is working.  <br/> I have tried link from the second para of the answer. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 71):

Try `pip install scikit-build`. For me, `pip install cmake` works properly afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me while installation of this github repo https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3

```
# For pip
pip install scikit-build
# For pip3
pip3 install scikit-build
```