# I'm having trouble downloading the slycot library using terminal via pip

Tags: python, macos, terminal

So I'm trying to download slycot via pip and I keep getting errors. To be completely honest I'm not totally familiar with terminal prompts and how all that works. Here is what I'm getting when I run, `sudo -H pip3 install slycot`

Here is what terminal publishes with that command:

```
Collecting slycot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/9d/7ed3f2abf08aab0be9ac2b67e3040c20d9c594cce6a4af2203da0c28a6c4/slycot-0.3.5.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Missing build requirements in pyproject.toml for slycot from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/9d/7ed3f2abf08aab0be9ac2b67e3040c20d9c594cce6a4af2203da0c28a6c4/slycot-0.3.5.0.tar.gz#sha256=cad98d5ea4f0a034cf398c39189f587620a0b03f1d4b71e77cd622a327f13adf.
  The project does not specify a build backend, and pip cannot fall back to setuptools without 'setuptools>=40.8.0' and 'wheel'.
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  Complete output from command /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpz94vocr1:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 25, in <module>
      from skbuild import setup
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 207, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 197, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 54, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 112, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 211, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 126, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 28, in <module>
      raise ImportError('sckit-build must be installed before running setup.py')
  ImportError: sckit-build must be installed before running setup.py

  ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpz94vocr1" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-t9m8s8yp/slycot
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've now tried `pip install scikit-build` and this returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-build in /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages (from scikit-build) (20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=28.0.0 in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-build) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.29.0 in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-build) (0.33.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages (from packaging->scikit-build) (2.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from packaging->scikit-build) (1.12.0)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've also tried, `pip install cmake` and this returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: cmake in /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages (3.16.3)
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably have more errors, please attach them

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 4):

You have another error with the installation of `slycot`, you have a dependency on `skbuild`.

In order to fix it check this site that gives you the compiled binaries to the `skbuild` package and try again [and maybe cmake as well]

Try this

```
pip install scikit-build; pip install cmake
```

You can read here for more details and ways to make this work.

[Not able to install skbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154143/not-able-to-install-skbuild)

Comment: I tried both of those and each one returns, "requirement already satisfied"

Comment: this is your erros:
  ImportError: sckit-build must be installed before running setup.py
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'